# Erro ao acessar instancia EC2 da amazon via ssh

Tags: amazon-aws, cloud

Estou tentando acessar uma instancia EC2 da amazon via ssh a partir do meu linux-ubuntu. 
Já criei a máquina no console da amazon, criei um key pair , dai o que fiz (pelo que entendi que teria que fazer) no meu pc, fui até a pasta onde baixou a `my-key-pair.pem` e dai rodei o comando

```
chmod 400 my-key-pair.pem
```

depois

```
ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ubuntu@ec2-51-207-86-54.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

e dai me deu esse erro

```
Warning: Permanently added '51.207.86.54' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Estou fazendo algo errado ou qualquer coisa de um iniciando nesse mundo aws.amazon?

Comment: Bom jovem, acredito que esse não é o lugar correto para perguntas que não estão relacionando a programação. Talvez você deve-se modificar um pouco ela.

Answer (score 4):

A mensagem de erro não indica um problema de conectividade, mas sim um problema de autenticação.

Algumas possíveis causas:

- vc está passando no parâmetro `-i` uma chave privada que não corresponde ao Key Pair com o qual lançou a instância (note que não é o "nome" do arquivo que importa, mas sim o conteúdo -- se vc tiver criado o Key Pair, apagado, e criado novamente com o mesmo nome, então são 2 Key Pairs distintos e não vai funcionar);
- o nome de usuário `ubuntu` não corresponde ao nome de usuário *padrão* da AMI que vc escolheu;
- vc está usando uma AMI "esquisita", que não configura apropriadamente a chave pública no usuário;
- vc lançou a instância sem associar a ela um Key Pair durante a criação;

Apenas com as informações que vc deu, fica muito difícil de determinar o problema. Siga as sugestões acima, e se não conseguir, tente adicionar mais informações à questão.

Answer (score -1):

Você cadastrou a key gerada no seu PC na lista de SSH Keys habilitadas para conexão?

Use:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_pub.rs
```

Vai exibir a key, em seguida copie-a e salve na lista no painel administrativo do servidor.

Para mais infos, siga este tutorial de como gerar a key e salva-la:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso tbm, mas não deu certo ... Ainda assim muito obrigado

Comment: O usuário padrão para acessar por ssh é ec2-user.

Tenta assim:
`ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-51-207-86-54.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: AlamoPS. VLW CARA. Era exatamente o usuario padrão que estava faltando no meu para acessar.

Answer (score -2):

Você deve gerar o arquivo .PPK, do seu arquivo .PEM utilizando o [PuttyGen](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/puttygen.exe) (64 bits) e então utiliza-lo, o .PPK como chave privada para acesso à instância.

Answer (score -2):

Eu consegui usando assim
**ssh -i <sua.pem> ubuntu@<dns da sua instância>**
acredito que precisa do ubuntu@ para identificar o usuário da instância, no caso a minha é uma instância do ubuntu e é criado um usuário padrão 'ubuntu'

Answer (score -3):

Eu já tive esse mesmo problema. Resolvi fazendo o seguinte:
1 - a permissão do <arquivo.pem> deve ser 400 (-r--------).
Para isso faça:$> chmod 400 <nomedoarquivo.pem>;
2 - Logue usando o SSH:
$> ssh -i <arquivo.pem> ubuntu@dns_publico ou ip_publico

Pronto! Espero que resolva.